# Как правильно добавлять зависимости на GitHub?

Tags: github, opencv

Я сделал проект, который использует библиотеку OpenCV и для тренировки хочу загрузить его на GitHub. Планируется, что человек из репозитория сможет скачать как уже скомпилированный .exe файл, так и исходный код. Как правильно добавить исходный код с библиотекой OpenCV, чтобы человек мог скачать исходники и сразу их скомпилировать? И возможно ли это вообще? Или лучше в README указать зависимости, чтобы человек перед компиляцией сам их подключал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь менеджером пакетов. Для OpenCV [есть пакеты](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d3d/tutorial_general_install.html) и для [conan](https://conan.io/) и для [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) и для [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/opencv).

Вам нужно только указать зависимость и менеджер пакетов сам установит/скомпилирует opencv. То как конкретно указывать зависимость зависит от того, какую систему сборки используете и какой собственно менеджер выберете.